# Asp.net routing parameter primary key to surrogate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have an ASP.NET (not mvc) application, and I would like to use route mapping for turning a url which includes a surrogate key (which the end users are familiar with and use for refering to the various items) say www/entity/321654789, into a call into a page using the prinary key, like so: www/page.aspx?id=103457

What is the best approach for doing this?  My research only found two methods, custom url route handler and having the page know about the new parameter.  Is there a better method? And if not, which of the two known methods is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing is a 2-way map. As far as I am aware, extending RouteHandler can only be used to map incoming routes. But for *generating* URLs (for linking between your pages), this approach won't work.

So, a better option is to [inherit RouteBase](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=970) (or Route) for advanced route customization. You just need to override GetRouteData to map a URL to a dictionary of route values, and [override GetVirtualPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850264/mvc-4-custom-route-html-action-out-of-synch/20853576#20853576) to map a dictionary of route values to a URL. By convention, both methods should return `null` if they don't match any value (and the routing framework will then attempt the next Route registered).

Then just configure your custom route in your RouteConfig file.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // Add a custom Route instance.
        routes.Add(new MyCustomRoute());

        // Add other routes...
    }
}
```

As far as your surrogate key is concerned, there are a few different approaches you could use.

- Cache the key-surrogate key mapping in a Dictionary. Lookup the key from the map and add it to the route values in GetRouteData, and do a reverse lookup key-surrogate key for GetVirtualPath.
- Cache the key-surrogate key mapping in a Dictionary. Lookup the key from the map and do a 301 redirect to the page with the key in the URL. There would not need to be a reverse lookup in this case.
- Use either of the above approaches, but use a different caching strategy. It is possible to use [file caching](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileCache/) or a [distributed cache](http://memcached.org/) with System.Runtime.Caching.